# How to host a package on NuGet.org?

Tags: nuget

I have an open source project [SystemWrapper](http://systemwrapper.codeplex.com/). Someone recently [asked me to add it to NuGet gallery](http://systemwrapper.codeplex.com/discussions/261756).  I had no problem to create a [NuGet](http://nuget.org/) package.  However, I cannot figure out how to add my package to NuGet Gallery.

Can someone point me to a link that describes how I can do that or tell me the steps I need to make.

Comment: Check this link: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package .. Also I could get to this link with a couple of clicks from nuget home site..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the page at http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package may be what you're looking for.

The basic process appears to be to register for an account at NuGet.org, tell your local NuGet package manager your API key, then "push" your component.

Good luck!